# When returning from contacts pick activity, the app closes without exception

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

In my Android application, when I pick a contact from the Contacts activity, instead of returning to the activity that called it, the  application closes without any exception or error message.

I tried to launch this activity with different flags, but with no result

```
class AddPhoneCompatActivity : BaseCompatActivity(), AddPhoneContract.View, View.OnClickListener {
    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: AddPhonePresenter

    override fun init(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    log("Add phone screen - Loading view", LOGS_SIMPLE_FILE_NAME)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_phone)
    MyLocationNotifierApp.getInjector().inject(this)
    presenter.attach(this)

    GeneralUtil.checkPermission(
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        GeneralUtil.READ_CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE,
        applicationContext,
        this
    )

    presenter.checkIntent(intent)

    btnAddPhoneFromContacts.setOnClickListener(this)
    btnPhoneNext.setOnClickListener(this)
}

    override fun onBackPressed() {
    goBack()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when(item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            goBack()
        }
    }

    return true
}

private fun goBack() {
    intent.setClass(this, AddLabelCompatActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(GeneralUtil.PHONE_SERIALIZATION_KEY, edAddPhoneNum.text.toString())

    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v?.id) {
        btnAddPhoneFromContacts.id -> {
            log("Starting contacts picker", LOGS_SIMPLE_FILE_NAME)

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)
            intent.type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE;
            startActivityForResult(intent, GeneralUtil.REQUEST_CODE_SEARCH_CONTACT)
        }

        btnPhoneNext.id -> {
            presenter.proceedNext(edAddPhoneNum.text.toString(), intent)
        }
    }
}

    override fun updatePhoneEditField(phoneNum: String?) = edAddPhoneNum.setText(phoneNum)

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    log("Add phone screen - onActivityResult called. Checking passed data.", LOGS_SIMPLE_FILE_NAME)

    if (requestCode == GeneralUtil.REQUEST_CODE_SEARCH_CONTACT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            presenter.processAddPhoneRequestFomIntent(data)
        }
    }
}
```

}

It is supposed that after picking a contact, I return to the activity and show a dialog with the list of phone numbers corresponding to the contact. But instead, the the app closes without any notification.

Comment: are you seeing the log line `Add phone screen - onActivityResult called` ?

Comment: also, share how your activity is defined in your `AndroidManifest`, some flags there can prevent `startActivityForResult` from working properly

Comment: @marmor
_are you seeing the log line Add phone screen - onActivityResult called ?_

No, after picking a contact I don't return to the activity

Comment: @marmor  
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`  
and:  
`<activity  
                android:name=".components.addphone.ui.AddPhoneCompatActivity"  
                android:label="@string/title_activity_add_phone">  
            <meta-data  
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"  
                    android:value="com.caesar84mx.mylocationnotifier.components.addlabel.ui.AddLabelCompatActivity"/>  
        </activity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. The entity creation flow is not using startActivityForResult, but the pieces of data passed between activities. And I started this flow in the starting activity using flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. When I deleted this line in the starting flow activity, it began working as intended.